# Explanation why testing with Subject RXJS fails and with BehaviourSubject succeeds

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, rxjs, jestjs

In this Angular application, I want to wait for some data to be loaded before attempting the login.

At first I implemented it with a `Subject`, like this:

```js
private _requiredDataLoadedSubject$: Subject<boolean> = new Subject();
private get _requiredDataLoaded$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._requiredDataLoadedSubject$.pipe(
    shareReplay({ refCount: true, bufferSize: 1 })
    );
}
```

Using it like this:

```js
  private _loadRequiredData(): void {
      this.integrationService.loadData$().subscribe(data => {
          this._requiredDataLoadedSubject$.next(true);
      })
  }

  login(): Observable<boolean> {
    this._loadRequiredData();
    return this._requiredDataLoaded$.pipe(
      switchMap(() => integrationService.realLogin();
      )
    )
  }
```

It works when serving it but, when testing it, I couldn't make the test pass. The subject is `undefined` when test reaches login.

Changing the `Subject` implementation to a `BehaviorSubject` one (that keeps state), the test passes.

```js
private _requiredDataLoadedSubject$: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject(false);
private get _requiredDataLoaded$(): Observable<boolean> {
    return this._requiredDataLoadedSubject$.pipe(
    filter(value => !!value),
    shareReplay({ refCount: true, bufferSize: 1 })
    );
}
```

In the test I do something like this :

```js
describe("WHEN: login", () => {
  const CHAT_MOCK = CHATS_RESPONSE_MOCK[0];
  let workgroupsloaded;
  beforeEach(() => {
    spyOn(integrationService, "loadData$").and.returnValue(of(DATA_MOCK));
    spyOn(integrationService, "realLogin").and.callThrough();
    service.login().pipe(take(1)).subscribe();
  });

  it("THEN: should call integrationService.realLogin", () => {
    expect(integrationService.realLogin).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

If someone could explain why this happens it would be great! Thank you! :)

### UPDATE

I understand the difference between `Subject` and `BehaviorSubject`. The thing I do not understand is why `Subject` implementation does not work in the test.

I'll explain. Because of how the execution pipe works, in `Subject` implementation:

- When *login()* refers to `this._requiredDataLoaded$`, the subject is not yet initialised, so it will wait until data comes.
- When *integrationService.loadData$* returns the value, the subject is updated.
- When the subject is updated, the observable *_requiredDataLoaded$* pipe its new data.
- When the observable *_requiredDataLoaded$* returns data, *login* should call *integrationService.realLogin*

Comment: hint:  `filter(value => !!value)`

Answer (score 0):

When you emit with `Subject.next`, since no subscription is done, the value is "lost".

The difference with `BehaviourSubject` is that whenever a new subscribe arrives, the latest emitted value is re-emitted. That's why the code works.

Comment: Do you know why when serving the application this works? I understand what you say but I find weird that it only fails in the test

Comment: Hum..I was reading again the question. You say the error is that the subject is undefined when you call login? Like you a `cannot call pipe from from undefined`?
Also, when you change from Subject to BehaviourSubject, you also include a filter there, right?

Comment: Yes, so the BehaviourSubject only emits true values.